# Python 2 csv files parser that outputs what is in file1.csv but not in file2.csv

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, csv

Since is my first post I want to say hello all, and I'm glad to be in this awesome comunity! I want to learn programing and I decided to start with python, I already have like 2 months in python, so I'm at a beginner level.

My first challange is to help a friend that have the following situation, I can understand basic python functions but the script I need is a bit complex for my lvl.

So I have 2 csv files (file1.csv, file2.csv), I need to check based on a index[**codfiscal**] from file2.csv in each line if that index is in file1.csv in any line, and if it isn't print all that line in file3.csv.
To give a example to better understand my problem I will post some samples examples:

### **Input:**

## file2.csv

Denumire;**codfiscal**;jreg;adresaCOR;adresaNLC;judet1;localitate;tipclient;stare;nu plateste la soc:;Stare firma;an_jreg

"""ACNORD""-P SRL";**15444630**;J2/614/2003;  NR 14;  NR 14;ARAD;SANMARTIN;PJ;FUNCTIUNE;ENEL;active;2003

"""ARBU""- TOY SRL";**12766886**;J2/122/2000;  SOS. CURTICI- DOROBAN?I NR F.N.;  SOS. CURTICI- DOROBAN?I NR F.N.;ARAD;CURTICI;PJ;FUNCTIUNE;ENEL;active;2000

(IN.A.P.S) INARCH PREMO STRUCTURES SRL;**16420906**;J2/844/2004;  B-DUL GENERAL VASILE MILEA NR 3 ET 2 AP 11;  B-DUL GENERAL VASILE MILEA NR 3 ET 2 AP 11;ARAD;ARAD;PJ;FUNCTIUNE;ENEL;active;2004

?IRU CONSTRUCT SRL;**22802765**;J35/4342/2007;  STR. TESATORILOR NR 8A ET 4 AP 10;  STR. TESATORILOR NR 8A ET 4 AP 10;TIMIS;LUGOJ;PJ;FUNCTIUNE;ENEL;active;2007

?OLEA INTER-COM SRL;**16918200**;J2/1887/2004;  NR 276;  NR 276;ARAD;GROSENI;PJ;FUNCTIUNE;ENEL;active;2004

## file1.csv

Denumire;**codfiscal**;jreg;adresaCOR;adresaNLC;judet1;localitate;tipclient;stare;nu plateste la soc:;Stare firma;an_jreg

"""ACNORD""-P SRL";**15444630**;J2/614/2003;  NR 14;  NR 14;ARAD;SANMARTIN;PJ;FUNCTIUNE;ENEL;active;2003

"""ARBU""- TOY SRL";**12766886**;J2/122/2000;  SOS. CURTICI- DOROBAN?I NR F.N.;  SOS. CURTICI- DOROBAN?I NR F.N.;ARAD;CURTICI;PJ;FUNCTIUNE;ENEL;active;2000

(IN.A.P.S) INARCH PREMO STRUCTURES SRL;**16420906**;J2/844/2004;  B-DUL GENERAL VASILE MILEA NR 3 ET 2 AP 11;  B-DUL GENERAL VASILE MILEA NR 3 ET 2 AP 11;ARAD;ARAD;PJ;FUNCTIUNE;ENEL;active;2004

.A.S.A. SERVICII ECOLOGICE SRL;**14822567**;J2/648/2002;  ZONA CET - SOSEAUA CENTURA NORD NR FN;  ZONA CET - SOSEAUA CENTURA NORD NR FN;ARAD;ARAD;PJ;FUNCTIUNE;ENEL;active;2002

?AIZAR CONS SRL;**23957563**;J11/441/2008;  B-DUL REPUBLICII NR 25 SC 3 ET 8 AP 29;  B-DUL REPUBLICII NR 25 SC 3 ET 8 AP 29;CARAS-SEVERIN;RESITA;PJ;FUNCTIUNE;ENEL;active;2008

?ICA - STRONG SRL;**15528110**;J2/745/2003;  STR. OCSKO TEREZIA BL 11 SC B ET 2 AP 6;  STR. OCSKO TEREZIA BL 11 SC B ET 2 AP 6;ARAD;ARAD;PJ;FUNCTIUNE;ENEL;active;2003

?IGHERTU CONSTRUCT SRL;**19298294**;J2/2238/2006;  STR. CEZAR NR 5;  STR. CEZAR NR 5;ARAD;ARAD;PJ;FUNCTIUNE;ENEL;active;2006

### **Wanted Output:**

## file3.csv

Denumire;**codfiscal**;jreg;adresaCOR;adresaNLC;judet1;localitate;tipclient;stare;nu plateste la soc:;Stare firma;an_jreg

?IRU CONSTRUCT SRL;**22802765**;J35/4342/2007;  STR. TESATORILOR NR 8A ET 4 AP 10;  STR. TESATORILOR NR 8A ET 4 AP 10;TIMIS;LUGOJ;PJ;FUNCTIUNE;ENEL;active;2007

?OLEA INTER-COM SRL;**16918200**;J2/1887/2004;  NR 276;  NR 276;ARAD;GROSENI;PJ;FUNCTIUNE;ENEL;active;2004

This are my csv samples, edited them a little so that you can see them better(ignore the spaces).

Important, my real data is like 100k lines on file1.csv and 50k lines on file2.csv. So the script must handle big data. I had this data on xcell files and I suposed that will be more easy to work with cvs and then convert  back!

Thanks so much for your time, all help will be greatly apreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
codfiscal_in_f1_set = set()
with open("file1.csv", 'r') as f1:
    for line in f1:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
            continue

        codfiscal_in_f1_set.add(line.split(";")[1])

with open("file2.csv", 'r') as f2, open("file3.csv", "w") as output_file:
    for line in f2:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
            continue

        codfiscal = line.split(";")[1]
        if codfiscal not in codfiscal_in_f1_set:
            output_file.write(line + "\n")
```

Comment: Wow, this is close, the output in file3 is the common elements from file2 and file1, I need what is in file2 but not in file1. File3 output are the one with the '15444630','12766886' and '16420906', I need the lines with 22802765 and 16918200 on the wanted output.

Comment: Denumire;codfiscal;jreg;adresaCOR;adresaNLC;judet1;localitate;tipclient;stare;nu plateste la soc:;Stare firma;an_jreg
"""ACNORD""-P SRL";15444630;J2/614/2003;  NR 14;  NR 14;ARAD;SANMARTIN;PJ;FUNCTIUNE;ENEL;active;2003
"""ARBU""- TOY SRL";12766886;J2/122/2000;  SOS. CURTICI- DOROBAN?I NR F.N.;  SOS. CURTICI- DOROBAN?I NR F.N.;ARAD;CURTICI;PJ;FUNCTIUNE;ENEL;active;2000
(IN.A.P.S) INARCH PREMO STRUCTURES SRL;16420906;J2/844/2004;  B-DUL GENERAL VASILE MILEA NR 3 ET 2 AP 11;  B-DUL GENERAL VASILE MILEA NR 3 ET 2 AP 11;ARAD;ARAD;PJ;FUNCTIUNE;ENEL;active;2004

Comment: I need ?IRU CONSTRUCT SRL;22802765;J35/4342/2007;  STR. TESATORILOR NR 8A ET 4 AP 10;  STR. TESATORILOR NR 8A ET 4 AP 10;TIMIS;LUGOJ;PJ;FUNCTIUNE;ENEL;active;2007
?OLEA INTER-COM SRL;16918200;J2/1887/2004;  NR 276;  NR 276;ARAD;GROSENI;PJ;FUNCTIUNE;ENEL;active;2004

Comment: I've edited the solution to reflect the changes to need in the comments. Hope that works

Comment: Perfect, that worcked amazing, where I can learn more about what you did in that code(sets I supose)? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use Python set. Assuming that the number is always in the 2nd column:

```
#load CV2

inCv2Set=set()
with open("file2.csv",'r') as file2:
   data=file2.read().split(' ')
   numbers = map(lambda x: x.split(';')[1],data)
   inCv2Set=set(numbers)

outFile=open("file3.csv")
with open("file1.csv",'r') as file1:
   data=file1.read().split(' ')
   header=data[0]
   data=data[1:] # to remove head
   #loop over the data and insert if not in the set
   for d in data:
        if not d.split(';')[1] in inCv2Set:
             outFile.write(d+'\n')
outFile.close()
```

If you do not know the position further manipulation over the head can be done

Comment: Thanks for reply, I got this error when I run my code:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 699, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 74, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "D:/proiect/csvwork/parser.py", line 2, in <module>
    with("file2.csv",'r') as file2:
AttributeError: __exit__

Comment: If I try to import cv2 I get this >
D:\proiect\csvwork>parser.py
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 9 but this version of numpy is
 6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\proiect\csvwork\parser.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

Comment: for the import cv2 error .. it is a different issue. you should update numpy appearntly

Comment: In anaconda I get now :

Comment: Good, hope the answer helps you.

Comment: I posted the error here, File "D:/proiect/csvwork/parser2.py", line 4, in <lambda>
    numbers = map(lambda x: x.split(';')[1],data)
IndexError: list index out of range, still dont work.

Comment: Ok this can be either you have empty rows in the data.. or the seperator  is incorrect.

Comment: Replacing `data=file2.read().split(' ')` with `data = filter(lambda x: x.strip(), file2.readlines())` should fix the out of range error.

Comment: @Xiflado that worked, but now I got this: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 699, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 74, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "D:/proiect/csvwork/wetry.py", line 14, in <module>
    if not d.split(';')[1] in inCv2Set:
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: if not d.split(';')[1] in inCv2Set: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I tryed to print inCv2Set and I got this : set(['15444630', '22802765', 'codfiscal', '16420906', '16918200', '12766886']), is the 'codfiscal' string the problem?

Comment: No , the error says IndexError: list index out of range which means that it goes out of size of the list. Most probably it is the problem of empty lines. Just check if the line is empty or not before continuing.